# Can I disable anti-aliasing in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, anti-aliasing

I'm currently working on some very small images in Photoshop. It always tries to anti-alias the edges, but this makes them really blurry on this scale.

Is there any way to turn this off, so I can draw sharp edges?

Comment: Edges? For which tool?

Comment: Most of them. Most annoying are the brush and when deleting a selected area. When I have a black object, on a a white background and try to delete a part, the edge will become grey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge... Photoshop doesn't anti-alias most things.  (I believe font layers are... but that's another subject)  I believe you're referring to "feathered edges" or are working with "semi-transparent areas".  You either need to remove the alpha-channel from the layer... (meaning no transparency) or be sure not to use tools that select/create soft-edges or have a feathered edge.

Comment: For what it's worth, here's a good explanation of anti-aliasing.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-aliasing

Comment: That page shows exactly what's happening. The image near this Title shows it (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-aliasing#Signal_processing_approach_to_anti-aliasing). The left is what I want, the right is what I get.

Comment: You're working with semi-transparent pixels.  try grabbing the pen tool... with a 1px square shape... (make sure it's not a feathered edge or something weird) and color that one pixel.  You'll quickly find it's not black or white... or grey... but rather black... with 50% transparency (or so)  The paintbrush tool typically has a feathered edge... to make it behave more like a "real" paint-brush.

Comment: You meant the pencil tool? Because the pen only makes a path. The pencil seems to work fine, thanks :)

Comment: yeah... sorry the pencil looks like a pen... but you know what I meant. :D

Answer (score 0):

For those who come after, I believe that the issue here is that your shapes are not aligned to the pixel grid.

Tips:

- show the ruler, and right click it, set to pixels
- zoom to 100% so that:

  - nudging with arrows moves exactly a single pixel, and
  - Holding shift constrains guide movement to the currently selected ruler units.
- when free transforming, click the top left (any but centre, really) anchor point and set the x/y values to whole pixels
- right click the dimensions and set to pixels, then set to whole pixels
- when creating shapes, click the options drop-down and set 'snap to pixels'

More details: http://memelab.com.au/photoshop-tips-aligning-guides-to-the-pixel-grid/