# How to draw a line wich is 1 pixel width and many pixels length without anti-aliasing?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, anti-aliasing

I wish to draw long black line in Photoshop with no anti-aliasing.

If I use Line tool it draws line with anti-aliasing. I.e. any imprecise line location relative to the pixel margins produce partially colored pixels near the line. While I need exact one selected color drawn.

I can use Pencil tool with 1 pixel size but and the result is ok, but it is hard to draw long lines with a Pencil.

[image]

Comment: Related: [Can I disable anti-aliasing in Photoshop?](https://superuser.com/questions/375493/can-i-disable-anti-aliasing-in-photoshop)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Select pencil tool.
2. Now you have 2 options:

   - To draw vertical or horizontal lines: Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and drag (your mouse movement will be limited to x or y axis)
   - To draw any other straight lines: click on the beginning of the line (you see a dot), move your mouse to the end of the line, hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and click.
     A straight line will be drawn between the two points you clicked on.

Comment: Best (and IMHO the only proper) answer.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more than once.

Answer (score 5):

The shape tools have 3 different drawing modes:

1. Shape Layers
2. Paths
3. **Fill Pixels**

The first 2 create vector shapes, whereas the last creates raster shapes. If you select `Fill Pixels` you can uncheck `Anti-alias`, which will then do what you want.

Alternatively, for horizontal and vertical lines, you can use the column and row selection tools. And for other angles, you can use the pen tool to create the path and stroke the path using the pencil tool.

If your problem isn't antialiasing (which is usually a good thing) but rather blurry lines where you want them to be crisp, then you just need to make sure your lines/paths are aligned with the pixel grid. But to do this, you'll need change your line/path's reference point to one of the corners instead of the center; otherwise, the line will be drawn between pixels, causing each adjacent pixel to be partially filled rather than a single pixel being completely filled.